# What do you call the front windshield/view of a car?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the front section that a car driver stares at while driving? I am not necessarily thinking about the front windshield, but the part the driver stares at while driving.

For example:

> The car was filled with junk so that the driver could only see a part
>   of **the windshield**.

I am trying to replace the bolded part.

Comment: UK English is **windscreen**.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/windscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

- The car was so filled with junk that the driver could only see **through** part of the windshield.
- The car was so filled with junk that the driver could **barely see** the road

Note that "so" should be in front: this is the construction which says the car had enough junk that we get the consequence.  If there was less junk we wouldn't have the consequence.  "It was so cold the pond froze".

Your sentence "... so that *goal*" is the construction usually used for giving the intended purpose of filling the car with junk.  "He put petrol in the car so it would work."